# Dynamic range slider and input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that shows that the value of the slider and does some simple math and displays the result.

I am trying to show the `value1, value2, value3` in a input field. When the slider is changed the value of the input should change. or when the input is changed the slider changes automatically.

```js
function updateTextInput() {

  var value1 = document.getElementById("range").value;
  document.getElementById('value1').innerHTML = "Roll Under:  " + "<b>" + value1 + "</b>" + " ";

  var value2 = (0.95 / value1 * 100).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('value2').innerHTML = "Multiplier:  " + "<b>" + value2 + "</b>" + " ";

  var value3 = (value2 * 10).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('value3').innerHTML = "Profit:  " + "<b>" + value3 + "</b>" + " ";

}
```

```html
<span id="value1">Roll Under: <b>47.5</b> </span><span id="value2">Multiplier: <b>2</b> </span><span id="value3">Profit: <b>20</b> </span>


<!-- Should be replace with <input id="value1"><input id="value2"><input id="value3"> -->

    <form>
      <input id="range" type="range" min="0.01" step="0.01" max="94" value="47.5" oninput="updateTextInput(this.value);"  >
    </form>
```

I tried something like this `<input id="value1input">` to replace `<span id="value1">Roll Under: <b>47.5</b> </span>` and   `document.getElementById('value1input').value=value1;` but when the user change the value in the input the slider does not change accordingly.

There should be 3 inputs for `value1, value2, value3`, and changing any input should change the other 2 input values and the slider.

Comment: all 3 inputs can be editable or only first one?

Comment: all inputs are editable @VaraPrasad changing one should change the other 3

Comment: You want to replace slider with input textbox ?

Comment: i think slider value,input1 value will be always same right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will helps you

```js
    function updateTextInput() {

        var value1 = document.getElementById("range").value;
        document.getElementById('value1').innerHTML = "Roll Under:  " + "<b>" + value1 + "</b>" + " ";
        document.getElementById('value1input').value = value1;

        var value2 = (0.95 / value1 * 100).toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById('value2').innerHTML = "Multiplier:  " + "<b>" + value2 + "</b>" + " ";
        document.getElementById('value2input').value = value2;

        var value3 = (value2 * 10).toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById('value3').innerHTML = "Profit:  " + "<b>" + value3 + "</b>" + " ";
        document.getElementById('value3input').value = value3;
    }

    function changeTextInput(elemnt) {
        var target_id = elemnt.id;
        var rangeval = parseFloat(elemnt.value).toFixed(2);
        rangeval = parseFloat(rangeval);
        switch (target_id) {
            case "value2input":
                rangeval = (0.95 / rangeval) * 100;
                break;
            case "value3input":
                rangeval = (0.95 / (rangeval/10)) * 100;
                break;
        }
        document.getElementById('range').value = rangeval.toFixed(2);
        updateTextInput();
    }

    updateTextInput();
```

```html
<span id="value1">Roll Under: <b>47.5</b> </span>
<span id="value2">Multiplier: <b>2</b> </span>
<span id="value3">Profit: <b>0.02</b> </span>
<br><br>
<input id="value1input" onchange="changeTextInput(this)">
<input id="value2input" onchange="changeTextInput(this)">
<input id="value3input" onchange="changeTextInput(this)">

<form>
    <input id="range" type="range" min="0.01" step="0.01" max="94" value="47.5" oninput="updateTextInput(this.value);">
</form>
```

Comment: i think this is what the OP wants

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code and snippet may help you,

```js
function updateTextInput() {
  var value1 = document.getElementById("range").value;
  document.getElementById('value1').innerHTML = "Roll Under:  " + "<b>" + value1 + "</b>" + " ";
  var value2 = (0.95 / value1 * 100).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('value2').innerHTML = "Multiplier:  " + "<b>" + value2 + "</b>" + " ";
  var value3 = (value2 * (document.getElementById("range").value)).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('value3').innerHTML = "Profit:  " + "<b>" + value3 + "</b>" + " ";
}

$('[data-input]').on('keyup',function(){
   var num=Number($(this).attr('data-input'));
   // validate min max here, if false then use 
   // return false, so you can prevent invalid values
   
   // clear other inputs except this,
   $('[data-input]').not(this).val('');
   switch(num){
      case 1:
          $('#value1 b').text(this.value);
          $('#range').val(this.value);
          break;
      case 2:
          $('#value2 b').text((0.95 / this.value * 100).toFixed(2));
          $('#range').val((0.95 / this.value * 100).toFixed(2));
          break;
      case 3:
          $('#value3 b').text(Number($('#value2 b').text())/Number(this.value));
          $('#range').val(Number($('#value2 b').text())/Number(this.value));
          break;
   }
   updateTextInput();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="value1">Roll Under: <b>47.5</b> </span><span id="value2">Multiplier: <b>2</b> </span><span id="value3">Profit: <b>0.02</b> </span>


<!-- Should be replace with <input id="value1"><input id="value2"><input id="value3"> -->

<form>
  <input id="range" type="range" min="0.01" step="0.01" max="94" value="47.5" oninput="updateTextInput(this.value);">
</form>
<br/>
Input 1 : <input id="value1input" data-input="1" /><br/>
Input 2 : <input id="value2input" data-input="2" /><br/>
Input 3 : <input id="value3input" data-input="3" /><br/>
```